# How to draw a polyline using the mouse and leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet

I would like to draw a polyline on a map with leaflet. The basic gesture that I would like to apply is:

- User clicks and holds on the mouse button -> that defines the first marker. If the user holds the mouse button, and moves the mouse, a corresponding "rubber band" is displayed.
- User releases the mouse button -> a second marker is added to the map and the 2 markers are linked by a line.
- Starting from the second marker, the user can continue building a second line using the the same procedure as above.

The final result should be the set of coordinates/markers, linked by a polyline.

Comment: I know nothing like what you describe. You may have to implement it. Why don't you use [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) which is amazing ?

Comment: Or any of the other [draw-like plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries), really.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As **Julien V** and **IvanSanchez** said, you can implement some of the draw-like [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries)

In example below:

You can see usage of [Leaflet.draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) plugin. Hope it helps :)

```js
// center of the map
var center = [46.165164, 15.750443];

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView(center,15);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
  'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);



// Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

var options = {
  position: 'topleft',
  draw: {
    polygon: {
      allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
      drawError: {
        color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
        message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
      },
      shapeOptions: {
        color: '#97009c'
      }
    },
    polyline: {
     shapeOptions: {
        color: '#f357a1',
        weight: 10
          }
    },
    // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
    polyline: true,
    circle: true, // Turns off this drawing tool
    polygon: true,
    marker: true,
    rectangle: true,
  },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
    remove: true
  }
};

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
map.addControl(drawControl);

var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'polyline') {
    layer.bindPopup('A polyline!');
  } else if ( type === 'polygon') {
   layer.bindPopup('A polygon!');
  } else if (type === 'marker') 
  {layer.bindPopup('marker!');}
  else if (type === 'circle') 
  {layer.bindPopup('A circle!');}
   else if (type === 'rectangle') 
  {layer.bindPopup('A rectangle!');}


  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

```css
html, body, #map { margin: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEST</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>
</html>
```